# Weird mouse problems. Accidental double-clicking, selection, drag-n-drop problems

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, mouse, troubleshooting

My mouse has started to double click or not keep a selection. Middle click works on the 2nd-3rd try, it ruins drag-and-drops and confuses selecting with opening things. It feels like little "refreshes" that cancel ongoing selections/drags/etc. This makes the pointing device entirely unreliable to the point of driving anyone insane. You think you know, but you have no idea. I would rather it not work at all.

I thought it was a hardware issue, but the mouse works fine on other PCs. This is a brand new HP mouse, a replacement for a previous one which died spectacularly (cursor all over the place, random clicks) some months ago.

I've tried:

- rebooting
- switching to another mouse
- messing with double-click speed in Mouse Settings
- a debouncing application
- uninstalling drivers
- using a different USB port

What's weirder is that certain things *slow down* the return of the issues:

- unplugging and re-plugging the USB cable
- switching the mouse buttons around in Mouse settings

I suspected some mouse filter drivers my anti-virus installed, but that turned out not to be the source of the problems after all... I also believe it may not have anything to do with HIDs at all, but with something else entirely that manifests like accidental clicks. Selecting text with the keyboard works fine.

Any ideas? 
I wouldn't like to re-install Windows for this.

<strike>**SOLVED (?)**: The problem suddenly vanished, everything has been fine for several hours. I believe **uninstalling [UxStyle](http://uxstyle.com/)** made it go away - that's the only change to my system I can recall.</strike> Nope.

Comment: Does it work as expected when you boot into Safe Mode?  how about if you boot into another OS (like say a Linux LiveCD)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked again and it turns out that it is indeed a **hardware issue**.

When I initially checked there probably wasn't enough time for the problems to surface, or it had good days and bad days. But now as it progressed, it's obvious that the mouse is bad. It's evident in Safe Mode, as well as on another machine running Ubuntu.

The mice have been damaged permanently, perhaps due to faulty USB ports on the motherboard. I say this because this is the 3rd mouse I've had develop this problem.

I'm reluctant to plug in any fresh meat until I get this question sorted:

#### Can a faulty USB port damage a mouse?

If so, can I verify? How would I do that?

Comment: In the initial question, you wrote "the mouse works fine on other PCs". Is this still true for your "damaged" mice? Also, I see it's been a while. Did you find an answer somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

It's most likely a problem with the switch (most likely Omron brand). I've had this problem on many Logitech mouses (expensives ones). To save money I had to change the Omron switches myself and now it's ok. You can also just try to fix the switches (you have to rebend a small piece of metal inside, it's not easy and won't last long).

Look on Youtube and you'll find tutorials.

Your USB port most likely doesn't have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: You are implying it is the mouse but the op that the mouse works fine on another machine and the same issue occurs with another mouse on the first machine. Can you shed some light on why your answer may work?

Answer (score 0):

can you advise if the mouse works fine otherwise?  i.e. does the mouse pointer move smoothly or does it judder, or occasionally stutter?

one thought i have is a hardware interrupt issue where the 'signal' from the USB connection is fighting with some other hardware?  if that is the case then other devices (especially USB) would also show issues.

other than that, it is possible you have a virus on the machine or a program which is trying to interact with the screen... like its trying to take focus.

Comment: The mouse works smoothly otherwise, and no other devices have any issues. There could be a virus on, although there are no other symptoms, and I have had (and recently upgraded) an anti-virus suite, which would get fussy if having to install on a compromised machine.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the Anti Virus suite would not install or complain if there is a virus - they are sneaky buggers!  the only way to be sure (and my next suggestion) is to download an offline antivirus tool that boots from a USB stick to do a thorough scan.  i'll dig out a link...

Comment: Try this for a few options [link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/system-security/tp/free-bootable-antivirus-software.htm).  i have personally used an (older) version of the F-Secure tool, and the Dr.Web tool and cannot remember having any issues with either.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've already scanned my PC from a USB CD-ROM with Kaspersky & BitDefender Rescue CDs, it turns up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the switch that is damaged and causing double clicks it is pretty impossible/unlikely for the usb port to be the issue. There are multiple IC's that sit in between the switches and the USB's UART bus.

I would look for other reasons you have been re encountering this problem. Maybe the way store your mice? Do you wrap them and put them in a bag? Just a thought. You could just be having statistically really bad luck.

Comment: How would storing one mouse in a "wrong" way cause the mouse to not work with the machine it normally is attached to but work with any other machines in the house and how would this mouse be able to cause all other mice (6 in my case) on this machine to also show the same error behaviour, including a brand new mouse fresh from the box?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a laptop on a docking station.. and both the track pad on the laptop, and a separate mouse are enabled to be used, pay attention to the surroundings on both.

I would constantly pile things onto my laptop since I didn't use that track pad. The weight of a notebook and a phone were holding down the click on the laptop track pad so I kept having random things dragged and dropped. As soon as I removed the items, the issue went away.

Keep your workspace clean and it should help!